# $\sigma(\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}) / \boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_\mathbb R$ measurable function on $ \boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}=\{[n,n+1):n\in\mathbb Z\}.$

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

In $\S 1.4$ of *Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration* by J. Yeh, the author provided an example:

> Let $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}=\{[n,n+1):n\in\mathbb Z\}.$ The $\sigma$-algebra spanned by $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C},~\sigma(\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}),$ is the collection of all countable unions of members of $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}.$ An extended real-valued function defined on $\mathbb R$ is $\sigma(\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}) $-measurable if and only if **it is right-continuous step function with jump discontinuity occuring at integers in $\mathbb R$ only.**

Now, it's easy to see that functions of such type are $\sigma(\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}) /
 \boldsymbol{\mathfrak  B}_\mathbb R$ measurable. But I am not able to formalize how it is the other way. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Measurable functions are constant on atoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is $\sigma(\boldsymbol{\mathfrak C}) $-measurable then $f^{-1} (\{f(n)\})$ is a union of the (disjoint) intervals $[k,k+1)$ and it contains $n$. Hence it must contain $[n,n+1)$. Can you finish?

In general, measurable functions are constant in atoms.

Comment: Appreciate your quick comment and the answer. Now to consolidate my thoughts: $f$ is constant a.e. on each atom $[n, n+1) $ and if $[k, k+1) \in f^{-1} (\{f(n)\})\implies k = n$ and subsequently we get the required step function that is right continuous at each integer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also, I would request you to add your comment in the answer.

Comment: Your argument is correct. I have included my comment in the answer.  @User1865345

Comment: Appreciate your advice. Thanks.